# Simple dashboard showing item count in simple bar charts

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, dashboard

I'm trying to build a very simple dashboard chart to show how many outstanding items someone has. Something like:

```
item 1 ------------------ (54 items)
item 2 ---------------------------------(74 items)
item 2 -------(10 items)
```

Ideally, I would like the dashes to be replaced by a simple coloured bar.

I've searched Google, but maybe using the wrong search terms. I'd prefer a C# solution but would be happy to use JQuery if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd need a little more information to solve this specifically, but here goes some ideas:

I assume you are rendering a collection of some kind, say in a Repeater or Gridview?

I would recommend a Repeater if you're not using it, as it can do pretty specific things in this situation, here is an example:

```
   <asp:Repeater id=Repeater1 runat="server">
      <HeaderTemplate>
         <table>
      </HeaderTemplate>

      <ItemTemplate>
         <tr>
            <td> 
               <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>
               <span class='backgroundBar' style='width:<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Count") %>px;'>&nbsp;</span>
               (<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Count") %> items)
            </td>
         </tr>
      </ItemTemplate>

      <FooterTemplate>
         </table>
      </FooterTemplate>

   </asp:Repeater>
```

Then

```
Object[] values = new Object[];

Repeater1.DataSource = values;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

And you can replace the dashed line with some kind of div with a background image, or anything styled the way you'd like.

** Make sure you use single quotes in your style property as double quotes will throw an error with the inline code **

Comment: Thanks.  Yep, I will be binding to a collection and I wasn't planning on using a repeater, but I after reading your reply a repeater sounds like a good direction.  I'm still confused about how I represent the item count with different length bars.  For example, the first item in my collection may have an item count of 50, and be 70px long, item 2 may have a count of 140 and be 180px long..do you know how I would represent this?

Comment: Sure. I would have an object specifically for binding to a repeater, with a property you can calculate in code behind, and then use that as a source for width. Editing answer to show.